# No proper definitions for the types of artificial agents

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agents

I have been searching for the definitions of the following:

1. Reflex agent
2. Model-based Agent
3. Goal-based Agent
4. Utility-based Agents

But I couldn't find anything. Most of the websites explain each with 2 sentences and one diagram which is kind of abstract. May be I am not good enough to understand them.

I really appreciate, if someone explain them in proper English.

Comment: Too broad. You probably need to read several books, starting with http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/

Comment: Thanks, just found the PDF and hopefully I'll find something.